# Program in java related to jsp

Tags: java

How to get values from a text box and display in a url in jsp

Comment: Your question is too vague.  Can you explain a bit more clear what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Use `method="get"` for your form and the values will automatically go into the URL when you submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="youraction.jsp">
  <input type="text" id="nameOfPerson"/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

by default form's action is `GET` , it will append param of form to URL.

So on clicking submit button you will get url something like

```
youraction.jsp?nameOfPerson=valueEntered
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
<script>
var url = window.location.href
</script>
<input onkeyup='window.location.href=url + "#" + this.value'>
```